# Render collection automatically in Symfony 2 using entity type form

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, entity, twig

I have a two entities: Products and Categories.
Each entity renders a custom form using the [Symfony Form Builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) .

I'm trying to include the Categories form inside the Products form using the [collection field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). The include line looks like the following:

```
$builder->add('idCategory', 'collection', array('type' => new CategoryType());
```

**It's working fine** (according to the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)). But I don't want to create the form with JavaScript, I want to have it rendered with the rest of the form without changing the twig template:

```
<form action="{{ path('product_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

Is it even possible? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this since it seems to be impossible to auto render the form without using JavaScript.

Instead of rendering the whole form at once, using `{{ form_widget(form) }}`, I'm rendering field by field and using `{{ form_widget(form.categoy.vars.prototype) }}` to render the Category collection. The template code looks like the following:

```
<div id="form">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    ... 
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(form.price) }}
    ...
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    {{ form_row(form.idCategory) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.idCategoryNew.vars.prototype) }}
    ...
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

And the ProductType:

```
$builder
    ->add('name'))
    ->add('price'))
    ...
    ->add('idCategory', 'entity', array('class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Category'))
    ->add('idCateogryNew', 'collection', array('type' => new CategoryType(), 'allow_add' => true))
    ...
```

**EDIT:**

I found a better workaround which consist in passing the collection form to the twig template. This way is easy to handle the post request after the form submission. If anyone want the code, please ask :)

**EDIT 2:**

Per @agapitocandemor request:

Inside your `MainEntityController` (ProductController in my case), search the method that renders the form (`newAction` in my case) and create the Entity form that you want to render:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Product();
    $entityform = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity);
    $subentityform = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), new Category);

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Product:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'entityform' => $entityform->createView(),
        'subentityform' => $subentityform->createView()
    ));
}
```

Finally, in order to render the `subentityform` you just need to call `{{ form_widget(subentityform) }}` from the `new` template of your main entity.

Comment: There you go. Hope you find it useeful

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the number of categories you want to include in the products?

Comment: No. I mean, the categories are dynamically created and stored in the database